# how do i run the script below

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem initialize all variables
set counter=1
set groupnumber=1
rem change groupcount value if you want a different number of files per zip
set groupcount=3
set zipfilenamePrefix=archive
rem start looping over...
for %%f in (*) do (
    if not "%%f"=="%~nx0" (
        set fileList=!fileList! %%f
        set /a reminder=!counter!%%!groupcount!
        if !reminder! equ 0 (
            set zipfilename=archive!groupnumber!.tz
            echo Zipping files: !fileList! into !zipfilename!
            rem your zipping utility goes here: input = !fileList! and output = !zipfilename!
            set /a groupnumber=!groupnumber!+1
            set fileList=
        )
        set /a counter=counter+1
    )
)
rem there could be some left over files - last group may be less than 3 files
if !reminder! equ 0 (
    set zipfilename=archive!groupnumber!.tz
    echo Zipping into files: !fileList! !zipfilename!
    rem your zipping utility goes here: input = !fileList! and output = !zipfilename!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't do anything.

At first you need to do what the comments say (add the archive-utility). Then save the code to a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and execute that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for creating ZIP files using 7-Zip. Fixes were applied and added more configuration variables.

It'll create multiple ZIP files with maximum of 100 files in each ZIP (configurable via `groupcount` variable) and save the zip file as *MyBackup##.zip* where *##* is a sequential number.

Typing `MAKEZIPS` alone without any parameter to show usage. An example for archiving all files (excluding subfolders) in folder `C:\My Data` and place the ZIP files to `D:\My Backup`:

```
MAKEZIPS "C:\My Data" "D:\My Backup"
```

Note: Don't put ZIP files into the same folder as the source folder, or it may cause endless loop.

If you use other archiver program (e.g.: *WinRAR*), you'll have to change the program path and most possibly its parameters.

`MAKEZIPS.BAT`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem initialize all variables
rem ***config start***
rem change groupcount value if you want a different number of files per zip
set groupcount=100
rem change zipfilenamePrefix value if you want a different base file name
set zipfilenamePrefix=MyBackup
rem change zipfileExt value if you are creating other archive type
set zipfileExt=zip
rem ***config end***
set counter=0
set groupnumber=1
if "%~2"=="" (
  echo Usage: MAKEZIPS {Source Folder} {Target Folder}
  goto :eof
)
if not exist "%~1\nul" (
  echo Source folder not found.
  goto :eof
)
if not exist "%~2\nul" (
  echo Target folder not found.
  goto :eof
)
pushd %2
rem start looping over...
for %%f in (*) do (
    if not "%%f"=="%~nx0" (
        set fileList=!fileList! "%%f"
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        set /a reminder=!counter!%%!groupcount!
        if !reminder! equ 0 (
            set zipfilename="%~1\%zipfilenamePrefix%!groupnumber!.%zipfileExt%"
            echo Zipping files: !fileList! into !zipfilename!
            rem your zipping utility goes here: input = !fileList! and output = !zipfilename!
            "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a !zipfilename! !fileList!
            if not exist !zipfilename! (
                echo ZIP creation failed.
                goto :eof
            )
            set /a groupnumber=!groupnumber!+1
            set fileList=
        )
    )
)
rem there could be some left over files - last group may be less than 3 files
if %reminder% gtr 0 (
    set zipfilename="%~1\%zipfilenamePrefix%%groupnumber%.%zipfileExt%"
    echo Zipping into files: %fileList% %zipfilename%
    rem your zipping utility goes here: input = %fileList% and output = %zipfilename%
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %zipfilename% %fileList%
    if not exist %zipfilename% echo ZIP creation failed.
)
popd
```